# inner div passes outside of outer div

Tags: css, html, height

I have an inner DIV which keeps passing outside of the parent div at the bottom only.
I'm reluctant to change the mobileArea settings as its part of my dreamweaver FGL.css

CSS:

```
#mobileArea {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: -1252px;
width: 100%;
width: calc(100% - 10px);
height: 830px;
display: block;
}

.mobileContent{
display: block;
height: auto;
margin-left:2px;
margin-right:2px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
border: solid;
border-color: #1D7C06;
 }
```

I've tried about every combination of things (apart from the correct thing), and can't understand why margin-bottom is not working.  I bet this is really simple but I cant find many similar posts.

Setup

```
<div id="mobileArea">
   <div id="logo">  No Set Height as it needs to change in size</div>
   <div id="links"> No Set Height as it needs to change in size</div>
   <div id="content" class="mobileContent">displays after links on a new line OK, 
       but continues out of parent div.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, it should be `id="mobileArea"` instead of `name=....`

Comment: Perhaps you could construct a live example on a site like http://jsfiddle.net/ That will help distinguish if mistakes like Maxime just pointed out (and you still have wrong - you have a `#` in the `id=` attribute) are the source of your problem or just mistakes in the example.

Comment: The website is www.allcoles.co.uk, then if you resize the window to very small.  You should see the issue I've got.  I just wanted to make it a little simpler for others with the same problem.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Why the enormous negative margin? Also try to better describe what you want and what goes wrong ...

Comment: Your URL doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Missing Id is just an TYPO

delete few css properties

```
#mobileArea {
 **clear: both;**Remove this line
 ....
 ....

 }
```

hope this would work

Answer (score 0):

```
#mobileArea {
    overflow: scroll;
```

The CSS style for `overflow` need to be applied to `mobileArea` and not the child `div`.

Comment: Inside my child div are further divs.  So I require the child div to have the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your site? - http://www.allcoles.com/

This will fix the position and make mobile main area a scrollable area:

```
.mobileContent - remove position:absolute
#mobileMainArea - overflow:scroll;
```

Of course you would want to throw this into a media query, since it looks like the page breaks at 706px you can do:

```
@media all and (max-width: 706px){
    .mobileContent - remove position:absolute
    #mobileMainArea - overflow:scroll;
}
```

Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks Mario, I have made some progress doing what I want it to do.  By changing mobileContent to absolute and bottom to 0pt, I had to change mobileMainArea to relative.  This has stopped it overflowing downwards, no I just got to work out how to stop it spilling over on the links and logo in the mobile sizes

Comment: Remove the following from .mobileContent - position, bottom, left, right, top. And add the following to #mobileMainArea - overflow-y:scroll;

Comment: Hi Mario, I want the child div to scroll with the content not the parent.  As there are further divs in the child div.

Comment: Set .mobileContent{height:695px;} ?

Comment: See that works and gives the effect I want, however if the links go down a line it still shifts it a little off the bottom